# Retrieve certain amount of items based on rangeKey without having to scan

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

Say I got some kind of forum/discussion platform, and have a dynamodb table that stores posts. The hash key would be some unique identifier, and the range key might be the timestamp the post was created at.

I now want to retrieve the 10 latest posts. However, I know that the scan operation is very expensive, and thus want to avoid using it. Is there any way for me to query the 10 latest posts WITHOUT having to perform a scan?

I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an GSI with an attribute like 'yyyy-mm-dd' as the hash key, and `timestamp` as the range key. Since it's possible that there are less than 10 comments in a single day, you may need more than one query, but that's fairly easy to achieve.

Pseudocode:

```
currentDate = today
while (results.size < 10)
    results.add(queryDynamoDB(currentDate))
    currentDate.subtract(1 day)
```

When querying the index, the query request should have

```
scanIndexForward = false
limit = 10
```

That way it will return up to 10 results which are the most recent timestamp for a given day.  You will only have to query more than one day if your forum is not very active, or a new day has just started. (Querying more than one day will not have a significant extra cost in RCU, just additional latency.)

**Edit:** Just to be clear, this is a GSI that I am proposing. The YYYY-MM-DD field is a field that exists just for the GSI. The main table should use some sort of unique (not time based) identifier as the hash key.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Wouldn't the timestamp already include the date, though, another attribute therefore being redundant? Is it somehow possible to just take the date out of the timestamp in an amazon query?

Comment: Using a 'yyyy-mm-dd' as a hash key may create **hot partitions**. It depends on your traffic, but if your site has many-many-a-lot-of posts per second think to use a hash key to a lower level of time granularity: 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm' for example. It depends on your traffic!

Comment: @Fly if the hash key is 'YYYY-MM-DD' you may omit that part in the range key. If it is a GSI it is ok, but generally keep in mind that the hash + range key is better to be unique. I usually append a random sequence at the end of the sorting key, thus you preserve the order and guarantee the unicity.

Comment: @Costin For a GSI, you don’t need to have unique keys, and the answer specifically says to use a GSI. Also, you don’t need to worry about hot partitions in a GSI.

Comment: @Fly, the timstamp does include the date, and honestly, whether that’s okay is completely up to you. The redundant information is only a handful of bytes. The important thing is what’s more useful to you, a `date` and a separate `time` attribute, or a time stamp attribute? You can’t use part of an attribute as a primary key component, so you do need two separate attributes for this approach. If you use `timestamp`, then you could reuse that attribute for other indexes in future. If you use separate `date` and `time` then your handcuffing yourself to always query them separately.

Comment: @MatthewPope I guess you are right, but can you give us some documentation for 'Also, you don’t need to worry about hot partitions in a GSI.'? I'd like to better understand how the GSI works. • I used the same solution without GSI, this is where my comment on hot partitions mainly comes from. Thanks.

Comment: @Costin I remembered wrong. You can indeed encounter back-pressure from an under-provisioned GSI. See slide 13: https://www.slideshare.net/mobile/AmazonWebServices/deep-dive-on-amazon-dynamodb-73191698

Comment: @MatthewPope Indeed, that is the image I had about GSI. I usually assume that a GSI has all the table constraints except key unicity and sparse index benefit. Thanks.

Comment: @Costin Yes. The only other thing to remember is that your GSI doesn’t have to have all the table attributes. If your GSI is keys only, then each write will be only one WCU against the index (unless you have really long keys).  In many use cases, you can get away with having a slightly hot partition in a GSI because the data in a GSI can be a subset of the full data. Furthermore, once the adaptive capacity kicks in for the GSI, you are pretty well protected from hot partitions.